# Ignoring symbols in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I have this code:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="expression">
<input type="submit" name="submitexpression">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitexpression']))
{
$getexpression = $_POST['expression'];

?>
```

If my input `$getexpression` value is: `((xyz))`, how do I ignore the parenthesis so that when I use `strlen` it only gives a value of 3 not 7?

Comment: Depending on the pattern but sounds like you need a regular expression.

Comment: 2x str_replace (replace parenthesis by empty string) and then strlen.

Comment: @Natrium i would like to ignore anything not in the alphabet i just put the parentheses coz im working on some kind of expressions.

and about strlen, i'm using for the character limit. my program would only accept 30 chars not including parentheses

Comment: The title says you want to ignore symbols, the body of your question says you want to ignore parentheses, and in the comments you say that you want to ignore "anything not in the alphabet". Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) is the better solution here as it will allow you to remove anything except alphabetical letters (as you requested in your comments):

```
$numChars = strlen(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $getexpression));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. now i can move one step on in my lambda project. lol

Comment: @Gorodetski You're welcome :) If you want to count space characters as well, all you have to do is change `/[^A-Za-z]/` to `/[^A-Za-z ]/`

Comment: ok sure ;) this preg functions seem really cool. it got my attention now lol

Comment: @Gorodetski They're called Regular Expressions (or Regex in short). Don't underestimate that subject though. Regex can be extremely complicated. Many programmers out there don't even dare touch it :P Still it's very powerfull if you're able to master it

Comment: @Downvoter: Please comment your reason for downvoting the answer so it may be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply strip-off the `(` and `)` using Regular Expression like so:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['submitexpression']) ){
        $getexpression = $_POST['expression'];
        // IF YOU MAY NOT KNOW HOW MANY "((" AND "))" TO EXPECT,
        // REGEXP IS A BETTER OPTION, OTHERWISE str_replace WOULD DO:
        $regX          = array("#(^\({1,})#", "#(\){1,}$)#");
        $getexpression = preg_replace($regX, "", $getexpression);

        var_dump($getexpression);
    }

?>
```

Comment: No need to get difficult. Read his comment: `i would like to ignore anything not in the alphabet`

Answer (score 0):

```
trim($getexpression , '(())');
```